# Video not recording full duration MediaRecorder javascript

Tags: javascript, codec, web-mediarecorder

I m trying to record videos using Javascript native MediaRecorder api with canvas. while setting options for the MediaRecorder if I set the mime type to `mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp8",` the output produces less duration video compared to video with no codec.

```
var videoStream = document.getElementById("canvas").captureStream(30);
    const options = { 
         mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp8",
         bitsPerSecond:1024000

      };

    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream,options);
    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = ((e)=>{
        this.generateVideo()
    })
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) =>{
        console.log("ondataavailable")
        if(e.data.size>0){
          this.chunks.push(e.data);
        }
        
    };
   },
generateVideo(){
      var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' });
      console.log("Video Size in Kb:"+ blob.size)
      this.chunks = [];
      const videoUrl =BlobHelper.createObjectURL(blob)
      localStorage.setItem("storeVideoUrl",videoUrl);
      this.isVideoCaptred = true
   },
```

Comment: How/when do you stop the recorder?

Comment: On clicking of start button

this.mediaRecorder.start()

On clicking of stop button

this.mediaRecorder.stop()

Comment: Then... how are you sure it took you the same amount of time between the two clicks, in both tests? I.e why should the durations be the same?

Comment: I clicked the start button  recording get started after 20 sec I clicked the stop button to stop the recording.  The expected video duration should be 20 sec, but it only records 5-6 second video